# Purescript Halogen Component function: Passing spaced arguments instead of a Record?

Tags: purescript, halogen

I'm on PureScript 0.8.2. In PureScript Halogen, the `component` function has the signature:

```
component :: forall s f g. ComponentSpec s f g -> Component s f g
```

where

```
-- | A spec for a component.
type ComponentSpec s f g =
  { render :: s -> ComponentHTML f
  , eval :: Natural f (ComponentDSL s f g)
  }
```

So `component` expects a record. But in the [Halogen Template Project](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen-template/blob/master/src/Main.purs#L22), `component` is called as follows:

```
ui = component render eval
```

Am I looking at two different `component` functions? or does arguments separated by space get converted into a record? So I tried the following in `psci`:

```
> type Point = { x :: Int, y :: Int }

> let
  addP :: Point -> Int
  addP p = p.x + p.y
> addP {x: 4, y: 5 }

9

> addP 4 5

Error found:
in module $PSCI
at  line 1, column 1 - line 1, column 8

  Could not match type

    { x :: Int
    , y :: Int
    }

  with type

    Int
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the template project hasn't been updated yet. Thanks for the reminder!

Assuming your `eval` and `render` functions are in scope you can use field puns to write the component definition this way:

```
ui = component { render, eval }
```

But yes, a record is always required now. I'll update the template project right away.

Comment: ah, got it, Thanks! I realized I didn't understand the nuance of `"purescript-halogen": "^0.5.14"` in `bower.json`. I thought it would pick up the latest version before 1.0 but it is not the case for versions below 1.0. Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004